# Customize Chatter Profile Page

Tags: community, chatter, user-profile

Hi is it possible to customize this whole page in the VF page.

[image]

Please advise

Comment: Yes, you can customize it. refer : **1.** http://salesforcedeveloperblog.blogspot.in/2012/03/custom-chatter.html       **2.**  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_profile_tabs_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_profile_tabs_cheatsheet/salesforce_profile_overview.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can customize the Chatter Page. U can add your own visual page to your chatter.

### Customize Chatter Profile Pages with Profile Tabs

#### Let Admins Customize Chatter Profile Pages.

> 1. From **Setup**, enter **User Interface** in the Quick Find box,then select **User Interface**.
> 2. Select Enable **Customization of Chatter
>      User Profile Pages**.
> 3. Click **Save**.

#### [Create Visualforce Tabs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_tabs_create.htm&type=0)  for your VF Page.

#### Now you have to add this Vf page into Subtab Apps.

> 1. From **Setup**, enter **Apps** in the Quick Find box, then select Apps.
> 2. You can find **Subtab Apps** section if scroll the page down. 
>      You can find 4 Subtab about Profile.
> 3. Click on **Edit** Profile , You can find
>      your newly created tab in **Available Tabs** , Move your newly
>      created Vf tab from **Available Tabs** to **Selected Tabs**.
> 4. Click **Save**

Now just click **Home tab**. Top you can find Your user Name in top, Click on that. So that it will re direct to your chatter feed.
Inside chatter you can find your sub tab on top click on that. you can see your pages.